# Norms on free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

here is my question :
Let $\mathbb{Z}$ equipped with the usual archimedean absolute value and $M$ a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $r$.

Can we define a norm on $M$ with the same definition of a norm on a vector space ?

Do you have some references for norms on modules ?

Thanks for help

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455320/generalizing-norms-for-modules.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The way we do this is by thinking of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$. In this case we call $\mathbb{Z}^n$ a [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)), and it inherits a norm from $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This is used frequently in the study of the [geomtetry of numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_of_numbers), and any book with that title will be a good reference. Lattices also show up in [Coding Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_theory#Linear_codes) and (in a slightly more general way) in [Lie Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(discrete_subgroup)).

As for references, one particularly fun example is Conway and Sloane's *Sphere Packing, Lattices, and Groups*. As for the geometry of numbers, I haven't actually read much myself, but I've heard good things about Siegel's *Lectures on the Geometry of Numbers*.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Also, if $\| n x\|=|n|\|x\|$ then the norm will extend to $\Bbb{Q}^n$ and to the completion $\Bbb{R}^n$, and we know they are all equivalent.